# if probability of $A$ and $C$ are independent and probability of $B$ and $C$ are independent, does it imply $A \cap B \cap C$ are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

I know that the answer is it's not always the case that $A \cap B \cap C $ holds.

I'm not sure why.
I tried to do this mathematically:
Because A, B, C are independent:
if $P(A \cap C) \cap P(B \cap C)$
then $ (P(A) * P(C)) * (P(B) * P(C))$
$\neq$
$ P(A) * P(B) * P(C) $

I know this is not accurate. Any way to show this more succinctly is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A:getting a black card from a deck
B:getting a red card from a deck
C:getting tails when flipping a coin 
A and C are independent and so are B and C. Yet, A B and C are not independent (proof by counter example)

Comment: @user6767509 Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: You should check your notation and grammar... It should read "If $A$ and $C$ are independent and $B$ and $C$ are independent, does it imply that $A,B,C$ are independent?"  You are using too many $P$'s and $\cap$'s in places where they shouldn't be.

Comment: As for a two second counterexample, consider the case where $A=B$.

Comment: @Arthur it's not done "mathematically" (using expressions) as asked. it's just an example on why it might fail

Comment: Even if all three pairs of events are independent, it's possible for the three events together NOT to be independent -- for example, flip a penny and a nickel and let the three events be: penny H, Nickel H, Exactly one H ... any two are independent but the set of three is not.

Answer (score 1):

First, recall that it is not “probability of two events are independent”, but “two events are independent”.

Second, probabilities are numbers so you can’t compute an intersection of probabilities. It just does not make sense.

For intuition, think that among three events, any two can be completely uncorrelated but the three may have some redundancy. A very general example is if $A$ and $B$ are independent and have probability $1/2$, then $C=A\Delta B$ (“either $A$ and $B$ occur, either both don’t occur”) is independent from $A$ and independent from $B$. However, if you know the results of $A$ and $B$, you know also if $C$ occurred, thus $A,B,C$ can’t be independent.